# Creating and modifying an empty Pandas DataFrame results in unpredictable behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand why my code, which initializes and then modifies a new column in a Pandas DataFrame, is behaving erratically.  My code is as follows:

```
pos = df['sign'] == 'Pos'
neg = df['sign'] == 'Neg'
df['signed_val'] = 0
df['signed_val'][pos] =  df['abs_val'][pos]
df['signed_val'][neg] = -df['abs_val'][neg]
df['pos_part'] = (df['abs_val']+df['signed_val'])/2
```

Here, `df` is an existing DataFrame that contains columns labeled 'abs_val' and 'sign'.  My goal is to create a new column with an additional row 'signed_val' that contains a signed version of 'abs_val'.

One of two things happens when I run this code.  First, if I copy and paste the entire block of code into my python interpreter, `df['signed_val']` will be filled with all zeros.  Alternatively, if I copy and paste one line at a time into my python interpreter, `df['signed_val']` appears to give a signed version of `df['abs_val']`.

Obviously, this behavior is unacceptable.  Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug?

**Update**:

The following code appears to run predictably as the last line prints out a signed version of `df['abs_val']`:

```
pos = df['sign'] == 'Pos'
neg = df['sign'] == 'Neg'
df['signed_val'] = 0
df['signed_val'][pos] =  df['abs_val'][pos]
df['signed_val'][neg] = -df['abs_val'][neg]
df['signed_val']
```

As soon as another command is run, however, `df['signed_val']` prints out a vector of zeros.  The following third block of code may run predictably, although I have not tested it extensively:

```
pos = df['sign'] == 'Pos'
neg = df['sign'] == 'Neg'
df['signed_val'] = numpy.nan
df['signed_val'][pos] =  df['abs_val'][pos]
df['signed_val'][neg] = -df['abs_val'][neg]
df['pos_part'] = (df['abs_val']+df['signed_val'])/2
```

Still, what is happening with the first code block?

I am using pandas version 0.13.1 and numpy version 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing chained assignment, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

on a single dtyped frame this will consistently work ; in general on a multi dtyped frame it will not.

instead, use the indexers `loc/ix` to reliably set values.

Comment: I'm curious that I don't see the difference between the 1st and 2nd code block, why they behave differently? Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean code `df['signed_val'][pos] =  df['abs_val'][pos]` should work even in the 1st code block, since `df['signed_val']` makes a reference, not a copy. Why the OP says it does not work? there seems nothing different between the first and the second code block(apart from the last line in code block 1).

Comment: You are missing the point, it will *only* work in a single dtyped case (and its clear this is *not* a single dtyped case). This *may* make a copy; it depends on whether numpy creates a view or not. Read the chained indexing section. Its not a reference in the python case. This goes thru pandas ``__getitem__``. This is why chained indexing is insiduous and should never be used. (also not clear which version of pandas is being used here; more recent version do provide a warning in *some* cases like this).